# converting rms to limit flux

Tags: magnitude, flux

My question is simple: if I have an RMS value (the standard deviation for my background) at 1 sigma, and I also have the zero point of my observation, how can I transform that value into the limiting magnitude of my observation?

Note that I'm working with optical data; units are adu while zero point is in ABmag

Comment: standard deviation and zeropoint in what units and in what data?

Comment: I'm working with optical data, units are adu while zero point is in ABmag